# Screen doesn't turn back on

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen

I have a brand-new Macbook Pro, my first mac since 1987, and unfortunately I'm experiencing a severe issue with it. If I leave it by itself for a while, or close the lid and then re-open it, the screen remains black and nothing I do can fix that - I have to forcefully shut down the mac (holding the power button for like 10 seconds) and re-open it.

I searched for this problem online and found many similar instances of it, but could not find any actual solution. How can I solve this issue? And if it's a still-unsolved problem, is there any work-around I can use to bring the screen back to life without rebooting the laptop?

---

Technical details, as copied from the About This Mac dialog:

```
MacBook Pro
15-inch, Late 2011
Processor  2.2 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory  8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
Graphics  AMD Radeon HD 6750M 512 MB
Software  Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2 (11C74)
```

- Running software update reports that the laptop is up-to-date.
- I only got it yesterday, and have managed to install a grand total of just 4 applications (Keka, Steam, Syncplicity and Chrome).
- I have *no* peripherals connected - the only physical connection is the power cord, the only wireless connection is the Wi-Fi. The problem persists whether the mac is connected to the power or not.
- The problem is consistent, once the screen turns off it's always doomed.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison Clicking the trackpad, clicking random keys, pushing the power button, closing and re-opening the lid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set the computer to *never* turn its monitor off and it took care of the problem - even after making the computer sleep and waking it up again it works.

I am now experienced a different problem, though, but as I cannot be positively sure it's related to this one I've opened a new question about it: [Why might a Macbook Pro go back into sleep shortly after waking up?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33123/macbook-pro-goes-into-sleep-shortly-after-waking-up)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a brand-new Macbook Pro

Well the obvious first solution that comes to my mind is: use your excellent AppleCare support service! Since it's brand new, presumably it's within the initial complementary AppleCare period. Their tech support is *awesome*, and if they can't solve the problem, you can take it in to an Apple store for repair, or they'll ship you a box and return shipping label to have the machine shipped to them and fixed, free of charge.

Comment: Well the only thing available here is taking it to the store, and if I can solve it on my own without doing it it will save me time, which is why I'm asking here. I was hoping there's some well-known solution or common workaround, given the relatively high number of related issues I could find.

Comment: You don't have free tech support via their 800 number? (1-800-MY-APPLE) [If you purchased your Mac within the past 90 days you're still within that period](http://www.apple.com/support/products/)

Comment: Hmm, turns out they do have a phone number here (though obviously not the 1-800 number), I'll give it a go.

Comment: Good luck Oak! Of course, I don't mean to imply I don't like to solve things on my own... I just know that Apple has great tech support and this was the first solution which came to my mind :-)